# Changing the language to lowercase in Next.js

Tags: next.js, locale, uppercase, lowercase

Is it possible to somehow change the language "DE" from uppercase to lowercase in URL in Next.js?
The translations are handled correctly, but only the URL is still staying uppercase.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do it with next.config.js file

```
// next.config.js
    
    module.exports = {
      i18n: {
        locales: ['default', 'en', 'de', 'fr'],
        defaultLocale: 'default',
        localeDetection: false,
      },
      tr

ailingSlash: true,
}
```

Reference: https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/i18n-routing

Comment: Internally, that URL is working fine. The translations are fetched correctly however, the URL still stays the same with uppercase "DE".

Answer (score 0):

I think you can also do something like this in your code:

{locale.toLowerCase()}